# What's the difference between shouldBe vs shouldEqual in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest

When should I be using shouldBe and when should I be using shouldEqual?

```
port shouldEqual 8000
port shouldBe 8000
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers:

> result shouldEqual 3    // can customize equality, no parentheses required
>
> result shouldBe 3       // cannot customize equality, so fastest to compile, no parentheses required

The first one takes an implicit `Equality[T]` to verify the computed value with the expected value, the second one doesn't. So if you just want to compare the port number `shouldBe` is sufficient.

Comment: " "should be" and shouldBe will likely be the fastest-compiling matcher syntax for equality comparisons, since the compiler need not search for an implicit Equality[T] each time." (from the same link)